# Halogenation of alcohols in the presence of ZnCl2

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, alcohols

I know that $\ce{OH-}$ is usually a bad leaving group, but why does the following reaction occur via SN1 in presence of anhydrous $\ce{ZnCl2}$?

[image]

Comment: Is $\ce{HCl}$ really part of your reaction equation? Because if it is you have no problem with $\ce{HO-}$ as leaving group as $\ce{HCl}$ would protonate the hydroxyl group converting it into a good leaving group.

Comment: I guess I'll make an answer out of my comment then :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are right, $\ce{OH-}$ is a bad leaving group. But the $\ce{HCl}$ in the reaction mixture protonates it. Thus, the bad leaving group $\ce{OH-}$ is converted to the good leaving group $\ce{H2O}$. Anhydrous $\ce{ZnCl2}$ might additionally facilitate the reaction by acting as a Lewis acid and it binds the expelled water thus preventing the back reaction.

[image]

Comment: +1, good answer. I just want to make one minor point: since the mechanism is SN1 and the carbocation intermediate is planar, one should get a racemic mixture of products. The representation of stereochemistry is therefore somewhat inaccurate and misleading, I think.

Comment: @GregE. Oops, sorry. You are completely right. I answered a question about $\text{S}_{\text{N}}2$ four hours ago and seem to have mixed that in. I've corrected my answer.

Comment: @Philipp How does ZnCl2 acts as lewis acid ? Does it uses it's empty 4s orbital?

Comment: @Lalit  https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14028/why-is-aluminium-chloride-a-lewis-acid-if-its-an-ionic-compound